# Imagick possibly incorrectly encoded Yii2

Tags: php, yii2, imagick

when I use imagick in side Yii2 I get error says :

```
"Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded.",
```

if I use imagick outside yii2 in any php file it will work I did take the same code and posted in a view file but I get the error

outside Yii2 view :

```
$img = 'http://127.0.0.1/web/project/uploads/imgl/d954b1f84f91ef24ce483922f2540c4b16704766371643751220/eaa190e9a65a7e120b1b37a297eff15c2027545943.jpg';
$gll = new Imagick($img); 
header('Content-type: image/jpeg'); 
$gll->blurImage(7, 3);
echo $gll;
```

Inside the view file of Yii:

```
<?php 
                    $img = 'http://127.0.0.1/web/project/uploads/imgl/d954b1f84f91ef24ce483922f2540c4b16704766371643751220/eaa190e9a65a7e120b1b37a297eff15c2027545943.jpg';
                    $gll = new Imagick($img); 
                    header('Content-type: image/jpeg'); 
                    $gll->blurImage(7, 3);
                    echo $gll;
                ?>
```

Comment: Try moving the `header('Content-type: image/jpeg');` header to the controller. You might be encountering a headers already sent error.

Comment: @KevinY: the same error

Answer (score 0):

View files are not designed for handling binary data. Instead have two separate routes: one for generating the image which would be done directly from the controller, and another route which can use the IMG within the view by linking to it.

Alternatively, if you don't wish to leave the view, you can also hack up something like this:

```
echo '<img src="data:image/jpg;base64,' . base64_encode($gll->getImageBlob()) . '" alt="" />';
```

But the suggested solution is to have two separate routes, one for generating the image, and another for using the image. When generating the image, there's no need to complicate it with a view.